# Compare 2 dates with a cte

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to compare 2 dates, I have one datetime and one varchar.
To do so I convert my varchar into a datetime and I insert it in a temporary table.

I tried with a cte but it didn't work, same result with a simple select.

Why does my request work with a temporary table and not with a cte ?

Using a table:

```
DECLARE @Tb TABLE 
( 
  DateCreation DATETIME,
  DateAchat DATETIME
)

insert into @Tb
SELECT
  Convert(datetime, DateCreation, 120), -- varchar
  Convert(datetime, DateAchat, 103), -- datetime
FROM MyTable


SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Tb WHERE DateAchat > DateCreation ORDER BY OrderId ASC
```

Using a CTE:

```
WITH cte ( DateCreation, DateAchat )
AS (
  SELECT
    Convert(datetime, DateCreation, 120), -- varchar
    Convert(datetime, DateAchat, 103), -- datetime
  FROM MyTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cte WHERE DateAchat > DateCreationenter code here
```

Comment: When you say it "does not work" - why? Do you get an error, no results, wrong results?

Comment: My error is "conversion of char data type to datetime data type resulted in an out of range datetime value"

Comment: There is something else gong on here.  That select statement would not behave differently.  That is not real code - @Tb does not have an OrderID.

Comment: yeah i just keep the interesting code

Answer (score 0):

You've got single quotes around the column names inside your CONVERT expression - this is not right if you are referring to the columns. You also don't need the CONVERT for the value that is already a DATETIME.

```
WITH cte ( DateCreation, DateAchat )
AS (
  SELECT
    Convert(datetime, DateCreation, 120), -- varchar
    Convert(datetime, DateAchat, 103) -- datetime
  FROM MyTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cte WHERE DateAchat > DateCreation
```

The range of the DATETIME datatype is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999. If you need a wider range or more precise times then you could use the DATETIME2 datatype.

Comment: Sorry my single quotes are not in my real request, it's just for my example

Comment: yes but when i used a temporary table it was work, and it's that i need to understand :)

Comment: In this simple case there will be no difference between a single SELECT, using a CTE, or using a temp table. I would guess a typing mistake or similar.

Comment: i think too but i used copy paste.
May be cte and temp table have a difference for interpret a convert datetime.

Comment: No - there will not be a difference between a single SELECT, using a CTE, or using a temp table in this case.